# Preventing IP spoofing

Tags: php

If I throw both of these two into a database, is that enough to prevent a site visitor from spoofing that they are coming from a different IP address?

```
$ip1 = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$ip2 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: What do you mean by _spoofing_? `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will show you the IP address of the remote endpoint, which is difficult to spoof in the middle of a connection, but easier to spoof closer to either end point of the connection -- but the program on that host might be maliciously impersonating one of your users. What are you really trying to measure or prevent?

Comment: @sarnold I want to allow an action only once every 5 minutes from a given IP address.  The idea is that one person would only be able to do the action once every 5 minutes, rather than clicking non-stop for hundreds of times a minute.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer - no. You can never **guarantee** a link between an IP and a person. For almost all practical purposes though, yes, that's good enough.

Unless you're really expecting someone to go to significant lengths to hide their IP, you should be fine.

It really depends on what you're trying to do as to whether it's good enough or not.

**Edit:** Just seen your comment on the first post. An option for that is to look at [Evercookies](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) - they're extremely invasive and unethical, but they do do a very good job, so it's your call.

Comment: Like I said, unethical as hell, but definitely cool. I wonder what the SOPA people would think of them :P

Comment: I'd never use it personally, but yeah, that's actually really neat. I don't think I had quite realized how many ways one can store a piece of identifiable information on a user's computer till now.

Answer (score 2):

`HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is an HTTP header, so it can be easily spoofed. `REMOTE_ADDR` is an environment variable provided by the web server as specified in the CGI specification. It can't be easily spoofed. So there's no real point in caching either one.

If someone is spoofing the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header using a compromised proxy server, then there's not much you can do about that.

However, it should be easier to trust that a non-proxied request isn't spoofed since, unless the attacker is on the same subnet, they're limited to a blind spoofing attack, which requires them to guess the sequence and acknowledge numbers of the TCP connection. This is very difficult to do on modern networks. And even if they managed to do this, they wouldn't be able to receive any data routed to the spoofed IP, so it would be easy to filter out any blind spoofing attacks.

These days, it's not really possible (ok, nothing is impossible, but it does require very specific circumstances and has limited applications) for someone to actually use a spoofed IP to make an anonymous TCP connection to a web server. At most packet spoofing is used for DDoS and flood attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it's very easy to spoof `X-FORWARDED-FOR`, which is literally sent as a header. Try making an account system or have it rely on email or something. You cannot trust IP alone.

Given your above comment, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will most likely suffice since they'd have to change IPs every time they wanted to perform that action, which would involve proxying or most likely Tor.

Answer (score 0):

No, you may only avoid using **some** proxy servers.

There are still options that allows you to "hide" your real IP (and many people like they privacy), such as:

- [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vpn)
- [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)
- ssh and for example [links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_%28web_browser%29)
- [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)
- connection from work, school, bar, friend...
- ...

IP logging helps you just again some kind of users anyway (and many of them uses dynamic ips from their provides pools so without court order you will never know who's that and ban many people with him/her) but against admin with 150 machines available...

Answer (score 0):

When any user visit your site with a proxy server in that case both value are different.You can get the IP address using HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR server variable.So in that case  'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' was posted by proxy server, which describe the client IP, while 'REMOTE_ADDR' describe the IP of proxy server.

When any user visit your site without any proxy server in that case you can get the IP address using REMOTE_ADDR server variable. So in that case HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and HTTP_VIA will not be available.